# CakePHP, pass parameter to js.php file?

Tags: javascript, cakephp

Im trying to use PHP to generate a javascript file. I have the file included and all scripts are workning in it. The think i cant figure out is how i pass a parameter to this file?

To pass a parameter from the controller to the view i use:

```
$this->set('object_models', $object_models);
```

To pass it from the view to a element i use:

```
echo $this->element('pageElement', array('object_model' => $object_model));
```

Im including my js.php file by adding it in the view with:

```
echo $this->Html->script('modelDrawer.js.php?', false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using `parseExtensions` and including your JS file as a view for a controller that you can perform logic on directly?

This would work similarly to the way rss feeds and xml files are generated with Cake.

[See this article](http://jamnite.blogspot.com/2009/04/integrate-php-into-javascript-in.html)

**UPDATE**

Go to your routes.php file, and add the line `Router::parseExtensions('js');`

Then, create a controller called, for the sake of this, `DynamicController.php` - and  paste this in there:

```php
class DynamicController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array();

    public function modelDrawer() {
        // logic in here
        $this->set( 'object_models', $object_models );
    }
}
```

Create a view folder and view file:

`/app/View/Dynamic/js/model_drawer.ctp`

In that model_drawer.ctp file, you can place your view/script logic that you want to be cakeified.

You can then call your script like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/dynamic/modelDrawer.js"></script>`

Give that a try!

Comment: Thanks for the input! Im trying to get the article explination working but i dont.. Probably alot of syntaxes that has been updated since it was written.. Would you care to help me out with a notice on whats changed? =)

Comment: Thank you verry much for the update! Alot clearer =) I still have a problem though, i have done what you told me but when i try to acess the /myProject/dynamic/modelDrawer.js i get an error _"Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!"_. In the model_drawer.ctp i got this just to test it: _"window.onload = function() { 
alert('testing');
}"_

Comment: sounds like you are trying to recursively add that script

Comment: I got it working!! I added _public $components = array('RequestHandler');_ to the controller and that did the trick =)

Comment: Neverending problems.. The generated JS file now contains <script>, is there a way to get rid of it? This is what i get output in the generated file: _<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() { 
alert('working!');
}</script>_ and this is whats in the .ctp file: _window.onload = function() { 
alert('working!');
}_

Comment: And there my problem was an existing default js layout that gave me the script tags, by editing the default.ctp layout for js files to _<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>_ everything is working! :D